# Доступ к ListView из другого потока

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-studio

Запускаю метод загрузки данных из БД из потока

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    getAvailableRecipes();
    }
});
thread.start();
```

В данном методе происходит присвоение адаптера ListView, но в итоге получаю ошибку, что сделать это можно из UI-потока. Каким образом я могу получить доступ к ListView и другого потока? В C# эта проблема решалась с помощью делегатов, а как обстоят дела в java? Воспроизвести по аналогии вряд ли смогу, поскольку с java на "вы". Есть ли какие-то отработанные методы решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Зачем вы удалили свой другой вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718085/progressbar-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-null?noredirect=1#comment1079812_718085

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вопрос не имел смысла, т.к. проблема была в моей невнимательности

Comment: Можно было б об этом в ответ написать. Может кому то потом и пригодилось бы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разделите этот метод на два:

1. загрузка данных (долгая операция)
2. обновление UI (в вашем случае это присвоение адаптера)

Вторую часть нужно выполнять в UI потоке, можно, например, воспользоваться методом [`runOnUiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) ([русская статья про этот метод](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/148-urok-85-esche-neskolko-sposobov-vypolnenija-koda-v-ui-potoke.html)):

```
void getAvailableRecipes() {
    ... загрузка данных ...

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        ... обновление UI ...
    });
}
```

---

Так как такой паттерн:

- Запустить долгую задачу в фоновом потоке
- Изменить что-то в UI на основе результатов задачи

часто встречается в андроид-приложениях, то разработчики придумали специальный класс [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), значительно упрощающий жизнь. [Вот русская статья про него](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html). Код с ним выглядит примерно так:

```
new AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
     protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
          ... долгая фоновая операция ...
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... progress) {
         ... обновление прогресса (можно оставить метод пустым) ...
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        ... обновление UI ...
     }
 }().execute(param1, param2, ...)
```

Некоторые пояснения:

- `Params` — класс параметров, которые вы будете передавать в `execute`. Можно не передавать никаких параметров и использовать `Void`
- `Progress` — класс, на основе которого будет обновляться прогресс (например, если `AsyncTask` скачивает файл, то это может быть `Integer`, представляющий процент скачанного). Можно никак не отображать прогресс и использовать `Void`
- `Result` — класс, который возвращает метод `doInBackground` и который принимает метод `onPostExecute`

Comment: спасибо, проблема решилась с использованием AsyncTask